# wxmaxima latex code gives me error when I use tcolorbox package

Tags: errors

I copy the latex code that wxmaxima gives me and I obtain minipage error
The code:

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside,spanish]{article}
    \usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
    \usepackage{units}
    \usepackage{endnotes}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}


    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{color,xcolor}


    \usepackage[total={15cm,21cm},left=2cm,top=2cm]{geometry}

    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}

     \newcounter{exe}

\newcommand{\titulo}{
   \node[fill=blue!20,
      rounded corners,
      draw=black,
      text=black,
      line width=1pt,
      inner sep=4pt,
      anchor=west,
      xshift=12pt]
   at (frame.north west){\bfseries Ejercicio \stepcounter{exe}\theexe.};
}

\newtcolorbox{ejercicio}{
   enhanced,
   overlay unbroken and first={\titulo},
   colframe=orange,
   boxrule=1pt,
   arc=3mm,
   breakable,
   top=15pt,
   before=\vskip18pt,
}


    \begin{document}
    \begin{ejercicio}
    A sample
    \end{ejercicio}
    \noindent
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%% INPUT:
    \begin{minipage}[t]{8ex}{\color{red}\bf
    \begin{verbatim}
    (%i1) 
    \end{verbatim}}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}{\color{blue}
    \begin{verbatim}
    divide(x^5-3*x^4+2*x^3-3*x^2+4*x+1,5*x^4-12*x^3+6*x^2-6*x+4,x);
    \end{verbatim}}
    \end{minipage}
    %%% OUTPUT:
    \definecolor{labelcolor}{RGB}{100,0,0}
    \begin{math}\displaystyle
    \parbox{8ex}{\color{labelcolor}\tt{($\!$\%o1)} }
    [\frac{5\,x-3}{25},-\frac{16\,{x}^{3}+27\,{x}^{2}-62\,x-37}{25}]
    \end{math}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \end{document}
```

The error message

```
Missing } inserted \end{minipage}
```

The error appears when I include tcolorbox package, i'm using a lot this package in my document.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't attach a maximal not working example.

Comment: As the first comment indicated, you need to re-arrange your example to be a single code section making a document that people can run that produces the error. Posting it as fragments does not help.

Comment: I can't because i've got this problem when i use this preamble. I think there's some incompatibility with some package or library.

Comment: Gradually remove packages and other code until the error disappears. Then put back the offending line(s). In this way you can produce a shorter example which reproduces the problem. See also [this question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/2417).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not connected with `tcolorbox`.
You have to put the closing bracket after `\end{verbatim}` in a new line because it is dropped otherwise:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside,spanish]{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}

\usepackage[total={15cm,21cm},left=2cm,top=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}

\newcounter{exe}

\newcommand{\titulo}{
   \node[fill=blue!20,
      rounded corners,
      draw=black,
      text=black,
      line width=1pt,
      inner sep=4pt,
      anchor=west,
      xshift=12pt]
   at (frame.north west){\bfseries Ejercicio \stepcounter{exe}\theexe.};
}

\newtcolorbox{ejercicio}{
   enhanced,
   overlay unbroken and first={\titulo},
   colframe=orange,
   boxrule=1pt,
   arc=3mm,
   breakable,
   top=15pt,
   before=\vskip18pt,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{ejercicio}
A sample
\end{ejercicio}
\noindent
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% INPUT:
\begin{minipage}[t]{8ex}{\color{red}\bf
\begin{verbatim}
(%i1)
\end{verbatim}
}%  ------------ new line! ---------------------------------------------
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}{\color{blue}
\begin{verbatim}
divide(x^5-3*x^4+2*x^3-3*x^2+4*x+1,5*x^4-12*x^3+6*x^2-6*x+4,x);
\end{verbatim}
}%  ------------ new line! ---------------------------------------------
\end{minipage}
%%% OUTPUT:
\definecolor{labelcolor}{RGB}{100,0,0}
\begin{math}\displaystyle
\parbox{8ex}{\color{labelcolor}\tt{($\!$\%o1)} }
[\frac{5\,x-3}{25},-\frac{16\,{x}^{3}+27\,{x}^{2}-62\,x-37}{25}]
\end{math}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!! It's strange, the error only appears if I add the tcolorbox package. When I copy/paste the latex code from wxmaxima it doesn't contain your fix.